# How to protect app from patching

Tags: android, google-play

I am making paid application and I check license using Google LVL library. But some patchers (like Lucky Patcher) can remove that license check. How can I protect it from patching or in what way I can make a remote server from license check?

Comment: You can't.  There's no way to prevent a sufficiently motivated hacker from removing any license checks you add, so long as he controls the hardware.  All you can do is make it slightly more annoying for him to do.  But since those people weren't going to pay anyway, its really not worth worrying about.  Focus on making sales to the people who will pay instead.

Comment: Thanks. But if I want to make remote server for license check, in what way I can secure license check?

Comment: You still can't.  I can always decompile your app and remove the check.  Unless you control the hardware, you can't prevent someone from accessing your app.  All you can do is provide a speed  bump and take him some extra time.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since anyone has access to your apk you can't prevent patching. Although you can make it way more difficult is several ways:

- Code obfuscation - ProGuard can do it for you, makes code barely human readable
- Add additional offline checks - you can access app signature using [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) and compare with yours. Nobody can fake your signature + code obfuscation will help to hide that couple of lines of code

Comment: Lucky Patcher edits dalvik-cache dex files, not touching apk, so signature does not change

Answer (score 0):

If your app uses data from a server, you can send the licence number with the requests and you can deny the answer when the licence is invalid.

Comment: How can I access Google Servers to check is user bought app?